# use prop for dynamic load image in quasar (vue 3)

Tags: javascript, image, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-props

Im trying to pass a prop into a component to dynamic load an image with the hname fetched from a database. Im trying to use the prop as an index but Im getting error. Should be pretty straightforward but something is wrong.

Parent:

```
 <Card :indexVal="pickedValue" />
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <div class="headlines-font">
      <div style="bottom: 0px" class="row content-around full-width q-px-lg">
        <div style="width: 30vw; color: white" class="q-pb-lg full-width">
          {{ actionData[indexVal].attributes.text }}
        </div>
        <q-img
          style=""
          :src="require(`../assets/${actionData[indexVal].attributes.img}`)"
          height="60%"
          class="q-ma-none bg-green q-mx-none"
        />
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { defineProps, ref, onActivated } from "vue";
import { dataStore } from "../stores/storage";
const stateData = dataStore();

const actionData = ref(stateData.getActionCardData);

const props = defineProps({ indexVal: Number }); //

</script>
```

The url is correct ... And if I just display

```
{{ indexVal }}
```

In template it shows up so the prop should be ok

I have also tried pass the url for the image and the text as props. It works with the text but not the image.

```
<Card
  boxClass="actions"
  :indexVal="pickedValue"
  :txt="actionText"
  :img="actionImg"
/>

<template>
  <div class="headlines-font">
      <div style="bottom: 0px" class="row content-around full-width q-px-lg">
        <div style="width: 30vw; color: white" class="q-pb-lg full-width">
          {{ txt }}
        </div>
          <q-img
            style=""
            :src="require(`../assets/${img}`)"
            height="60%"
            class="q-ma-none bg-green q-mx-none"
          />
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { defineProps, ref, onActivated } from "vue";
import { dataStore } from "../stores/storage";
const stateData = dataStore();

const actionData = ref(stateData.getActionCardData);

const props = defineProps({ indexVal: Number, txt: String, img: String }); //

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script setup>
const imageUrl = new URL('./logo.png', import.meta.url).href
</script>

<template>
<img :src="imageUrl" />
</template>
```

---

```
<script setup>
const imageUrl = new URL('/src/assets/images/logo.svg', import.meta.url)
</script>

<template>
  <img :src="imageUrl" alt="img" />
</template>
```

Doc - https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url

> Does not work with SSR
>
> This pattern does not work if you are using Vite for Server-Side
> Rendering, because import.meta.url have different semantics in
> browsers vs. Node.js. The server bundle also cannot determine the
> client host URL ahead of time.